# Trouble with application function vs if code

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Why this code not work. Anybody can help with simple code? I write the code like this:

```
Private sub cmbStart_click()
Dim bro as application
Dim bre as integer
Dim bru as control

For bre = 1 to 42
Set bru = controls("cmb" &  bre).caption
Set bro = application.worksheetfunction.vlookup(bre, sheets("keg").range("c2:f300"),4,0)
  If bro = "es" then
    Controls("cmb" & bre).backcolor = rgb(255,0,0)
  Else
  Controls("cmb" & bre).backcolor = rgb(255,0,0)
 End if
Next bre
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vlookup()` doesn't return an *application* so declaring `bro` to be an `Application` is pointless.

Simply

```
Dim bro As Variant
'...
bro = Application.Worksheetfunction.Vlookup(bre, sheets("keg").Range("c2:f300"),4,0)
```

Similarly, there is no reason to declare `bru` to be a *control*. The caption is simply a `String`.

Thus:

```
Dim bru As String
'...
bru = controls("cmb" &  bre).caption
```

VBA is mostly an imperative language which *uses* objects. You seem to be trying to make everything an object.

I am not in a position to test the code, but the above makes more sense as VBA.

If this doesn't fix the problem, you need to say a bit more about *how* the code doesn't work. Simply reporting that it doesn't work isn't very helpful.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Then the app is blocked on the line "set bru = controls("cmb"&bre).caption". I need a solution about this

Comment: @YanLimaBenua You had a similar problem with `bru`. There is no reason to declare it as a control rather than a string. See the edit.